# Не запускается Flutter

Tags: flutter

[image: Бесконечный дэбаг fluttera]

Бесконечная загрузка:
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

Также закрывается панель инструментов, где находятся кнопки Stop и т.д

В Flutter doctor стоят все галочки

Хотел научиться писать приложения на Flutter, но не запускается код

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.